# Stopping CountDownTimer when it is used as a method

Tags: java, android, methods, timer

I ran across an issue, I'm using a count down timer in a method as shown below, and call it at certain places in my application i.e. `scoreTimer();` I'm having a hard time figuring out how to stop it, I noticed a `.start()` method at the end of CountDownTimer and I assume there should be a `.stop()` method as well, but how can I apply it when I use a method - `scoreTimer()`?

```
        public void scoreTimer() {

        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                getTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                cycleState = 1;
                expressionCycle();
                if (currentCycle <= 10) {
                    scoreTimer();
                }

                System.out.println("SCORE: " + totalScore);
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the timer to a variable like this:

```
CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer...
```

And then you can invoke

```
mTimer.cancelTimer()
```